# Reasons behind non-intuitive C# String.Split() implementation

Tags: c#, performance, api-design

In C# if I want to split a `string` by another `string` I have to do something like that :

```
testString.Split(new string[] { "anotherString" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

From the overloaded [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) MSDN Documentation we can see the implementation and why such a call has to be made.

Coming from *Python*, It is hard for me to understand correctly why such a call is needed. I mean I could use [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a similar syntax than the Python's implementation but I would have to do it at the cost of less performance (setup time) for anything *simple*.

So basically, my question is why the hell can't we just do:

```
testString.Split("anotherString");
```

Note that I'm not suggesting any prototype nor implementation. I understand why you couldn't implement the above version considering the current API. My goal was to understand why such an API could have been created considering the benefit that the above syntax brings. As of now, *flexibility* seems to be the goal of the current [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) which make sense, but to be honest I really thought there was some sort of performance gain somewhere. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. My speculation is that they just didn't put much effort into designing this one API. And if they realized their mistake, it was too late.

Comment: @Caleth Can you elaborate on this. maybe I'm wrong but I don't see what's ambiugous about it. Why can't I do `testString.Split(",.;");` and `testString.Split(new Char [] {',', '.', ';',);` which are not the same thing.

Comment: @Euphoric I tought so too, but that would be so odd. Hope someone comes with a more logic answer.

Comment: You can iterate over a string just like an `IEnumerable<char>` so the additional prototype you are suggesting might appear ambiguous in certain cases (do you delimit by the whole string or delimit by each of its characters?) Just a guess.

Comment: @JohnWu Maybe it is a personal thing, But for 99.9% of occurrences of syntax like `testString.Split("anotherString");`, I'm pretty confident to say that the expected behavior was to delimit on the whole string (`anotherString` in this case).

Comment: `At least some hope arises` -- Is this issue really that profound?  I can think of many things that are much more bothersome in the .NET ecosystem, such as (to pick one random example among many) how difficult it is to mock `HttpContext` objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did I ever say that was an emergency ? _I'd like to have this feature_ doesn't mean _This language is crap without it_. I just believe it would be a nice feature that would really make sense.

Comment: @scharette - this, along with some for IDataReader and IEnumerable<T> are often the first extension methods I create/copy when starting a new project

Comment: @Liath Yes same here... Extension method is a quick fix, but as I said in a below comment though, in my opinion _All it does is let the community create different version of a method that everyone (or almost everyone) expect to behave the same way._

Comment: @scharette: Regarding your note about C# 8: Non-nullable types will not fix this, since it doesn't affect overload resolution.

Comment: @JacquesB you mean for the overloads already existing ?

Comment: @scharette: Non-nullable reference types will not affect overload resolution at all. "*There is no semantic impact of the nullability annotations, other than the warnings. They don’t affect overload resolution or runtime behavior, and generate the same IL output code.*"  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/

Comment: @JacquesB I will edit accordingly, your feedback is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes splitting on more than one char/string is useful, so the API allows you to provide an array, giving you maximum flexibility. In the case of `char`s, you get both simplity of syntax and flexibility since the parameter is marked as `params` so you can write `Split('x')` rather than `Split(new[]{'x'})`.

So why is there not a similar option for strings, allowing you to write `Split("x")`?

This is perhaps an unfortunate consequence of how the API is designed. Initially it only allowed splitting on chars. Spliting on strings was added in 2.0, probably because it is more complex to implement. But it was not possible to add `String.Split(string)` or `String.Split(string[])` overloads, since this would make the expression `testString.Split(null)` ambiguous and this code would not compile anymore.

`testString.Split(null)` is actually a pretty common idiom since it splits the string on whitespace, so such breakage would be too widespread to be acceptable.

Using a `null`-parameter as a switch for special behavior is generally considered bad design these days, so I think it is fair to say this API is just flawed.

There is no `Split(string[], Int32)` either, probably for a similar reason - it would be ambiguous with `Split(char[], Int32)` if the first parameter is `null`. There *are* similar overloads with the `StringSplitOptions` parameters, but these were all added at the same time in 2.0, so no ambiguity was introduced in existing code.

**Note**

To be clear, this is just my hypothesis, I don't know the actual thinking by the .net framework designers.

Comment: Well, is that at all useful? Doubt that. And it is only an API-break, not an ABI one.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Split(null) splits on whitespace, so it is probably one of the most common use cases for split, even though it is bad API design to use a null like this.

Comment: I think @Deduplicator wanted to say that `Split(null)` is useless if you allow `Split("")`. Besides the fact that it would allow a way better syntax, the latter is more verbose anyway...

Comment: @scharette: Sure, but it is not possible to change now, without breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: a note: with the current C# 8 preview, by turning off base types nullability `String.Split(null)` would no longer be ambiguous, so they could add the overload

Comment: Maybe they should have just bitten the bullet and accepted minor API-breakage (without ABI-incompatibility) for the convenience.

Comment: @BgrWorker: Sadly this won't work, since nullability is an optional configuration, so you would still have breakage if this option is not selected.

Answer (score 2):

Not being the author of the methods, I do not know why that set of overloads was chosen. However, there are two things to note here:

1. If you are splitting on a single character, then the `public string[] Split(params char[] separator`) version can be used thus:

   ```
   var splitValues = testString.Split(',');
   ```

   as the `char[]` is a `params` parameter.
2. You can easily add your own extension method here to achieve what you want:

   ```
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       public static string[] Split(this string source, string separator)
           => source.Split(new string[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
   }
   ```

   and now `testString.Split("anotherString");` will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although your answer is helpful and concise, I can't agree with you. Especially the second point. Isn't one more reason to have it built-in ? All it does is let the community create different version of a method that everyone (or almost everyone) expect to behave the same way.

Comment: Not trying to debate by the way, your point is entirely valid. Just trying to understand the reason behind this. Logically there must be a historical or performance reason...

Comment: @scharette: The reason is to make the method as general purpose as possible.  As preferable as you find your chosen method signature, it won't work for multiple delimiters.  Microsoft's version will work for multiple delimiters as well as your single delimiter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well wouldn't both be possible? Let's say the extension method in the above answer was part of `String` class, both would be possible. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  Your overload only allows one delimiter.  Microsoft's overload allows more than one.  You can't call your overload multiple times and achieve the same result; that's not how this works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yea ok I see what you mean. I'd argue that regular expressions are probably more appropriate when splitting on multiple delimiters, but that's maybe a personal thing.

Comment: Regular expressions can have some performance concerns, and an array of delimiters is arguably more intuitive.  I personally reserve regexes for more complex heavy-lifting.

Comment: True. opinions aside, your point is entirely valid, I didn't realise that. Would it be worth creating your answer ? Or suggest editing on @9000 answer since it seem related ?

Answer (score 1):

Different languages have somewhat different rules for implicit conversions and overloading, and the .NET Framework is designed to be usable with any of them.  In the `Option Strict Off` dialect of VB.NET, a value of type `String` may be passed to a function which expects a `Char[]` with behavior equivalent to calling `ToCharArray()` on the string.

I think the sensible thing to do would have been to have separate names for `Split` (which accepts a single `Char` or `String`) and `SplitMulti` (which would accept a `Char[]` or `String[]`), but .NET sometimes seems to favor using overloading alone to pick different kinds of operations.  Unfortunately, I know of no way to use `String.Split` to accommodate any usage scenarios that would require distinguishing different kinds of delimiters other than by splitting separately on each.

Another omission is an option to preserve delimiters, either including them at the end of the preceding string, or at the start of the following string, or having odd-numbered array elements be delimiters while even-numbered elements are the things between them.

Comment: _.NET sometimes seems to favor using overloading alone to pick different kinds of operations._ So true...